# Delete all empty folders, even with .svn folders in it

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, find

I'm trying to delete all empty folders within a directory. However, `find . -type f -empty` does not find anything because every folder contains a hidden `.svn` folder.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Are the `.svn` directories empty?

Comment: No, they are not. I think Ollis solution will work. However, I did not test it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you can off course first remove all `.svn` folders. Downside: you'll lose version control information, if someone is using SVN. If someone is using SVN, then it's not good idea to just remove those folders (or actually you have to remove those from SVN too, as SVN is tracking folders and files).

If that's not possible, I would go with scripting route:

```
for folder in $(find . -type d); do
 if [ "`ls $folder | wc -l`" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "I am going to delete $folder"
 fi
done
```

First try test-run, because there might be something surprising. Then you can change `rm -r` instead of that `echo`.

Note however, this will remove all folders with only dot-files (so for example `a/.this_is_super_important` will be deleted, if there is no other files or folders).

Answer (score 3):

Minor modification (simply print the directory and pipe into `xargs` later):

```
for folder in $(find -type d ! -path *.svn*); do
  if [ "`find $folder ! -path *.svn* ! -path $folder | wc -l`" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $folder
  fi
done
```

Put this somewhere in your `$PATH`, maybe as `svn-empties` and then first run:

`svn-empties`

to list which directories it found (modify list if necessary) and then pipe into `xargs`:

`svn-empties | xargs svn rm`

This script has become very useful to me while using `git-svn` (thank you!). Since `git` does not track empty directories I can end up with many empty directories in the Subversion repository. I `svn co` a separate copy of the repository and run `svn-empties | xargs svn rm` periodically. Using Subversion in the first place was not my decision ;)

Comment: If you are using `git-svn` you may want to use the `--rmdir` option of `git svn dcommit`. It will take care of removing directories from svn as soon as they are empty.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this and I used this script but modified it to properly consider empty dirs only the ones with .svn and no other file, hidden or normal.

Also, bear in mind that I am using svn rm, so this is suppose to work against a repository, you could adapt the script to do something different on the directory.

```
for folder in $(find -type d ! -path *.svn*); do
  if [ "`find $folder ! -path *.svn* ! -path $folder | wc -l`" -eq 0 ]; then
    svn rm $folder
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. resolved the problem that : spaces in Path
2. can call the script with PATH parameter like this:

`svn-empties YOU_WANT_TO_SEARCH_PATH`

```
C_IFS=$IFS

IFS=$'\n'

for folder in $(find "$1" -depth -type d ! -path *.svn*|sort -r); do
  counts=$(find "$folder" -type f ! -path *.svn* ! -path $folder | wc -l)

  if [ $counts -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $folder
  fi

done

IFS=$C_IFS
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with white space, `find` and `IFS` magic (filenames can actually contain newlines as well, so `IFS=$'\n'` is not a silver bullet), one could use globs and arrays.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
search_dir=${1:-.}
shopt -s globstar dotglob
for svn_dir in "$search_dir"/**/.svn/; do
    base_dir=${svn_dir%/.svn/}
    base_dir_contents=("$base_dir"/*)
    if [ ${#base_dir_contents[@]} -eq 1 ]; then
        printf 'The directory "%s" only contains ".svn/".\n' "$base_dir"
    fi
done
```

- The script takes an optional path argument, or uses the current path as default if missing.
- `globstar` enables the directory traversing `**` construct.
- `dotglob` includes hidden files in asterisk globs.
- The `for` glob should be safe against any problematic directory name characters. Globs will *always* expand safely in Bash, which is not the case with `ls`, `find`, etc. The trailing slash makes sure we only match *folders* named `.svn` and not *regular files* (a real corner case, though).
- The names of the files contained in the folder with the matched `.svn` directory are globbed into an array. If the number of items in this array is 1 (i.e. the `.svn` folder that we by construction *know** is there), then it is what we are looking for.

It only uses Bash built-ins and thus should be faster than issuing extra system forks for `find`, but the difference is most likely not noticeable, and I/O will be the main bottleneck anyway.

---

*: Minor sidenote (applies to the other solutions as well): there is a potential race condition if there is e.g. only the `.svn` and the `foo` file in a directory, and the `.svn` directory is removed between the `for` and the array glob which would result in `foo` being removed as well. However, if someone with malicious intent has the privilege to remove files in the file system, the game is probably already lost, and they could easier be removed directly than through timing attacks.

---

Another quick mention is that the other answers should quote their `*.svn*` expansions. Otherwise the `find` command will fail if the current folder contains a file that matches that glob:

```
$ mkdir foo && cd foo
$ mkdir -p test1/.svn test2
$ find -type d ! -path *.svn*
.
./test1
./test2
$ touch foo.svnbar
$ find -type d ! -path *.svn*
.
./test1
./test1/.svn
./test2
$ find -type d ! -path "*.svn*"
.
./test1
./test2
```

Without quotes, `*.svn*` will be prematurely expanded by the shell to `foo.svnbar`.